# Как в миграциях бд Flyway добавлять данные в таблицу типа blob

Tags: java, spring, flyway

Как в миграциях добавлять данные при инициализации таблицы типа blob? С другими данными понятно, но вот что с blob? Не передавать же мне в каждую строку в таблицы массив байтов, который огромной длинны?

Например я создаю таблицу, где есть поле типа blob и в этой же миграции я прописываю insert. Как мне провести insert в тип blob
[image: 1]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я не знаю, как еще более точно написать